# How to split a string but alter each word in the string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split

I'm trying to basically take an inputted sentence and alter each word slightly. This should work for any sentence.

So far I have this:

```
line = (input("Enter a sentence: "))
words = line.split()
for word in words:
    new_line = 'em-' + word[1:] + word[0] + '-ma'
print(new_line)
```

but all this does is take the last word in the sentence and does what i want it to do. I want each word to be altered where the first letter in each word is moved to the last place, and each word is "sandwiched" by "em-" and "-ma". Any advice?

update:

what if i did this?

```
line = (input("Enter a sentence: "))
words = line.split( )
for word in words:
    print('Result: ','em-' + word[1:] + word[0] + '-ma')
```

this gives me what I want but it repeats `result` over and over and the words are in a vertical line. how do i fix this?

Comment: `new_line` is over-written each time through the loop so you only end with the last one.

Comment: print inside the loop

Answer (score 2):

`new_line` is being replaced every time the loop is executed so in the `print` statement outside of the loop it has the value of the last word.

If you just want to print each word, move the `print` inside the loop.

If you want all of the words accessible outside of the loop, add them all to a list or replace the loop with a list comprehension:

```
new_words = ['em-' + word[1:] + word[0] + '-ma' for word in words]
```